# ClickOnce App as Terminal Services WebApp autoupdate?

Tags: clickonce, terminal-services

Will a clickonce app that checks for autoupdate on start autoupdate itself as a terminal services webapp? Will it check for and update itself like it would as a regular desktop app?

Answer (score 0):

To ClickOnce, the fact that you are running in a terminal service environment will be irrelevant. Every time a user logs onto a machine, whether it's different machines in a terminal server environment or differnet machines in an office, it will create a new deployment under his profile. So if you have terminal servers and 5 different people connect to the same terminal and run the application, you will have 5 deployments installed.

Even if you mark the application as online-only, it installs it (but only if the user can hit the online link).

And before you ask, there's no way to make a ClickOnce application run for all users.  (common question)

If you don't care about multiple versions, or everyone uses the same login, then it will work just fine.